# Accidentally deleted local branches after changing the workspace in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-branch, workspace

I accidentally lost all local branches after changing the workspace without saving it in VS Code. Now, the only branch I have is master. Is it possible to restore all these lost branches?

Tried to open my previous folder as a workspace, nothing happens

Comment: This is clearly a programming question, no idea who voted to close based on that. But it's not very clear. Please read [ask], then [edit] as many details into your question as possible. A [mre] would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have commited your local branches with the help oh git
then,

you can use
`git reflog` command.

the output will show you the `commit hashes`.

if you find the lost commit in the reflog, you can reset you branch using that `hash`.

for that, use
`git reset --hard <commit_hash>` 
( 'commit_hash' -- actual hash you found in the reflog)